# how to check "Is there any application in foreground or not" programmatically

Tags: android

I am developing an application, in which i want to check that is there any application is in foreground or not. I can get the list of running Apps through this code:

```
List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) 
{
            runningApplist.add(procInfos.get(i).processName);
            runningApplistpid.add(procInfos.get(i).pid);
}
```

now i can get the foreground application by sorting this list. But how to check is there any app in foreground or not
Also..... we can check that our app is in forground or not by this:

```
public Boolean foregroundAppgetter()
 {
    boolean check = false;
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : procInfos)
    {
       if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
       {
         check = true;
        }

     }
     return check;
  }
```

But what about other Applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always an application in the foreground, except when the device is just booting up.

Comment: i am asking in the sense ,when there is no "/data/app"(non system app) in the foreground.Just showing the Wallpaper

Comment: But how can I know which Application ?

Comment: @Peter: On modern versions of Android, you can't, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way if user will permit to check

Comment: @Peter: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have done something but it gives me only of My Application.